# Jcrop not cropping properly the images

Tags: javascript, java, graphics, bufferedimage, jcrop

My jcrop code

```
$(function(){

// Create variables (in this scope) to hold the API and image size
var jcrop_api,
    boundx,
    boundy,

    // Grab some information about the preview pane
    $preview = $('#preview-pane'),
    $pcnt = $('#preview-pane .preview-container'),
    $pimg = $('#preview-pane .preview-container img'),

    xsize = $pcnt.width(),
    ysize = $pcnt.height();

//console.log('init',[xsize,ysize]);
$('#target').Jcrop({
  onChange: updateInfo,
  onSelect: updateInfo,
  onRelease: clearInfo,
  setSelect: [0, 0, 150, 180],
  boxWidth: 400, boxHeight: 300,
  allowMove: true, 
  allowResize: true, 
  allowSelect: true,
  aspectRatio: xsize / ysize
},function(){
  // Use the API to get the real image size
  var bounds = this.getBounds();
  boundx = bounds[0];
  boundy = bounds[1];
  // Store the API in the jcrop_api variable
  jcrop_api = this;

  // Move the preview into the jcrop container for css positioning
  $preview.appendTo(jcrop_api.ui.holder);
});


   // update info by cropping (onChange and onSelect events handler)
function updateInfo(e) {
    if (parseInt(e.w) > 0) {
        var rx = xsize / e.w;
        var ry = ysize / e.h;

        $pimg.css({
            width : Math.round(rx * boundx) + 'px',
            height : Math.round(ry * boundy) + 'px',
            marginLeft : '-' + Math.round(rx * e.x) + 'px',
            marginTop : '-' + Math.round(ry * e.y) + 'px'
        });
    }
    $('#x1').val(e.x);
    $('#y1').val(e.y);
    $('#w').val(e.w);
    $('#h').val(e.h);
};

// clear info by cropping (onRelease event handler)
function clearInfo() {
    $('#w').val('');
    $('#h').val('');
};


   });

   Java controller which handles it

@RequestMapping(value = "/editProfileImage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
FileMeta edit(MultipartHttpServletRequest request,
        @RequestParam(value = "x1") final int x1,
        @RequestParam(value = "y1") final int y1,
        @RequestParam(value = "w") final int w,
        @RequestParam(value = "h") final int h) throws Exception {
    Iterator<String> itr = fileIterator(request);
    MultipartFile mpf = null;
    final FileMeta fileMeta = new FileMeta();
    // 2. get each file
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        mpf = getMultipartFile(request, itr);
        checkIfEmpty(mpf);
        checkifValidFormat(mpf);

        final BufferedImage subImage = getBufImage(mpf).getSubimage(x1, y1, w, h);

        //final BufferedImage resizedImage = resizeImage(subImage);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(subImage,
                mpf.getContentType().replace("image/", ""), baos);
        final Account account = accountManager.findBySigin((String) request
                .getAttribute("account"));
        profilePictureService.saveProfilePicture(account.getId(),
                baos.toByteArray());

        prepareMetaInformation(mpf, fileMeta, account, baos);
    }
    return fileMeta;
}
```

This code works fine for some images but dont work fine for most of the images. Does anybody has any clue.

For example for the following image [image]
It works perfect because i am getting the cropped image perfectly.

But for this image for example [image]
I am not getting the cropped image correctly.

Comment: I was removing the tag "java" before I really saw that java was included in the question. I am sorry. I have added "java" again, but I could not make it the first tag in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used below code and its works for me..Please go through below one.

Your Problem is Here:

```
setSelect: [0, 0, 150, 180],
```

which you are passing constant

```
jQuery(function ($) {

        // Create variables (in this scope) to hold the API and image size
        var jcrop_api,
            boundx,
            boundy,

            // Grab some information about the preview pane
            $preview = $('#preview-pane'),
            $pcnt = $('#preview-pane .preview-container'),
            $pimg = $('#preview-pane .preview-container img'),

            xsize = $pcnt.width(),
            ysize = $pcnt.height();

        console.log('init', [xsize, ysize]);
        $('#target').Jcrop({
            onChange: updatePreview,
            onSelect: updatePreview,
            onSelect: storeCoords,
            aspectRatio: xsize / ysize,
            boxWidth: 350, boxHeight: 350
        }, function () {
            // Use the API to get the real image size
            var bounds = this.getBounds();
            boundx = bounds[0];
            boundy = bounds[1];
            // Store the API in the jcrop_api variable
            jcrop_api = this;

            // Move the preview into the jcrop container for css positioning
            $preview.appendTo(jcrop_api.ui.holder);
        });

        function updatePreview(c) {
            if (parseInt(c.w) > 0) {
                var rx = xsize / c.w;
                var ry = ysize / c.h;

                $pimg.css({
                    width: Math.round(rx * boundx) + 'px',
                    height: Math.round(ry * boundy) + 'px',
                    marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * c.x) + 'px',
                    marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * c.y) + 'px'
                });
            }
            // storeCoords(c);
        };
        function storeCoords(c) {

            jQuery('#X').val(c.x);
            jQuery('#Y').val(c.y);
            jQuery('#W').val(c.w);
            jQuery('#H').val(c.h);


        };

    });
```

Please separate out this function from your code.

```
     function storeCoords(c) {

        jQuery('#X').val(c.x);
        jQuery('#Y').val(c.y);
        jQuery('#W').val(c.w);
        jQuery('#H').val(c.h);


    };
```

And place call storeCoords at your fixed coordinates you set earlier
as

```
setSelect:storeCoords ,
```

Answer (score 1):

Without having console logs showing errors that could potentially identify the problem, you'll have to settle for an inconsistency that I found.  ID tags are supposed to be used strictly for only one element.  I see that you are using an ID tag, presumably for multiple images.  This does not meet HTML 5 compliancy because IDs are meant for one object alone, and classes are meant for multiple objects.  You should switch to a class and iterate through the objects that have this class assigned to it.  For example:

```
$(".cropimages").each(function(index) {
  $(this).Jcrop({
    onChange: updateInfo,
    onSelect: updateInfo,
    onRelease: clearInfo,
    setSelect: [0, 0, 150, 180],
    boxWidth: 400, boxHeight: 300,
    allowMove: true, 
    allowResize: true, 
    allowSelect: true,
    aspectRatio: xsize / ysize
  }, function(){
    // Use the API to get the real image size
    var bounds = this.getBounds();
    boundx = bounds[0];
    boundy = bounds[1];
    // Store the API in the jcrop_api variable
    jcrop_api = this;

    // Move the preview into the jcrop container for css positioning
    $preview.appendTo(jcrop_api.ui.holder);
  });
});
```

With that code, be sure that all of your images use the class `cropimages`.  This should iterate through each, then crop them.  Also, make sure that you have all of the required libraries, and check the console for errors.