# Jcrop Bootstrap false coordinates

Tags: jcrop

i have some problem about jcrop sometimes it give me false coordinates i'll show images

First picture : x1 : 213.232 x2  : 125123.123
second picture : x1 : 120 : x2 : 250 example

and my codes so basic other problem in telephone mode max width nonoe doesn't work

```
$("img#krop").Jcrop({
        onSelect :showCoords,
        onSelect:    showCoords,
        minSize: [180,180],
        boxWidth: 700,
        boxHeight:  435

        //setSelect:   [ 150, 310, 320, 140 ]
        //setSelect: [0,0,940,600]
    });
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think its too less information to understand the problem. but is there any specific reason why u mentioned

```
onSelect: showCoords
```

twice?

Btw, which lightbox are you using?
Try to provide some more details, friend.

Comment: here is a related question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919733/jcrop-not-cropping-properly-the-images?rq=1) of JCrop although its a shot in the dark coz i still dont understand your problem but have a look.